# How to plot data from multiple text files in a single graph in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have finished the code so far that I have created a list that stores all textdatein and then iterates over them. However, it currently overwrites all previous text files and only plots the last one. What is missing in my code that all previous text files are saved and plotted and the last one too?

```
    def openFile(self):
        filelist = []
        for i in range(2):
            files = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            filelist.append(files)

        for fname in filelist:
            with open(fname) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                x = [float(line.split(",")[0]) for line in lines]
                y = [float(line.split(",")[1]) for line in lines]
                self.plot4.set_data(x,y)
                self.ax4.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
                self.ax4.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
                self.canvas.draw_idle()
                self.canvas.is_saving()
```

Comment: Please post the code for the whole class. It is unclear what the values of all the member variables are.

Comment: don't use `.set_data(x,y)` because it replaces previous values in plot. You should use `plot(x,y)` every data. OR maybe even `plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)` But both versions will plot all on one grid. If you need separated plots then you will need also `subplots()`

Comment: BTW: when you click `Cancel` in dialog `askopenfilename` then `files` will be `None` and you should check this before you add to `filelist`

Comment: How can i post my all code? When I try to do this, it says I have too many characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem are NOT files.

You replace values on graph using `.set_data(x,y)`

You should use `plot(x, y)` to add new plot/line to graph.

Problem can make also `.set_xlim()` `.set_y_lim()` because it will set for last `x, y`. And this may need to put data from all files in lists `all_x` `all_y` and at the end use `.set_xlim(all_x)` `.set_ylim(all_y)`

Because I can't test it so I don't know if it will need `plot(..., ax=self.ax4)` or `self.ax4.plot(...)`

---

It can be something like this:

```
def openFile(self):
        filelist = []
        
        for i in range(2):
            files = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            if files:
                filelist.append(files)

        # --- before loop ---
        
        all_x = []
        all_y = []
        
        # --- loop ---
        
        for fname in filelist:
            with open(fname) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                x = [float(line.split(",")[0]) for line in lines]
                y = [float(line.split(",")[1]) for line in lines]
                
                self.ax4.plot(x, y)
                
                all_x += x
                all_y += y
                
        # --- after loop ---
        
        self.ax4.set_xlim(min(all_x), max(all_x))
        self.ax4.set_ylim(min(all_y), max(all_y))
        
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.canvas.is_saving()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# --- before loop ---

all_x = []
all_y = []

# --- loop ---

for a in range(1, 10):
    
    t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
    x = list(t)
    y = list(a * np.sin(np.pi * t))
    
    ax.plot(x, y)

    all_x += x
    all_y += y

# --- after loop ---

ax.set_xlim(min(all_x)-0.1, max(all_x)+0.1)   # margin 0.1  
ax.set_ylim(min(all_y)-0.5, max(all_y)+0.5)   # margin 0.5

canvas.draw()

# ---

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a little error in thinking!

Comment: if it is small problem then you can write in comment. But rather you should create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and description. And code will be more readable. And new people may see it so more people may help you.

Comment: Do you know a smart solution, how i can fix this? : BTW: when you click Cancel in dialog askopenfilename then files will be None and you should check this before you add to filelist @furas

Comment: Can you help me with my other problem please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486577/how-do-i-delete-all-my-plots-using-a-tkinter-button 

@furas